# Best way to save user preferences when using Open CTI

Tags: opencti

Using Open CTI, I'm building a 3rd-party call center with a separate login to my system's telephony features. I need to save user preferences, like screen pop rules for instance. Is there a way to save preferences in Salesforce? I could save them to localStorage or cookies, but I'd rather have them not be machine-specific.

Comment: Consider using custom settings of the hierarchy type

Comment: Can that be done completely through Open CTI, without Apex? That's my goal.

Comment: I'm not certain I can answer that. I can only say that custom settings could be accessed via a visualforce page or the API. Whether or not you'd need APEX would depend on how you're doing your integration. If they're logged in through salesforce, presumably the hierarchy settings could be accessed through their user profile.